# IOS build failing in IONIC

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am getting “Error: doc.find is not a function” error when IONIC is trying to do IOS build.

IONIC is able to build Android successfully. Only issue is with IOS.

Ionic Info Output -

- Cordova CLI - 7.0.1
- Ionic CLI Version - 2.1.18
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: Windows 7
- Node Version: v4.4.4
- Xcode version: Not installed

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Kaddath for pointing that out, I corrected my question. I already installed IOS platform , but  let me remove and try to install it again. I will also try to install Xcode.

Comment: Xcode isn't available on Windows. You can't make iOS build on a Windows computer.

Comment: I was able to do it , by using ionic package build ios . Suddenly it stopped.

Comment: Ok, so I was able to resolve this issue. I created new folder copied my existing source code (excluding node_modules) and installed only specific plugins and it started working :)

I think custom-config-plugin which I was trying to use may have cause this issue(I did not installed that particular plugin in my new folder).  I think that plugin was not properly installed or something cause ios build to fail. Even i tried to remove this plugin from my old folder but may be some garbage from that plugin was still hiding in some libraries.

But now it is working fine. Appreciate your help!!